# How to Mount and Edit an Android Disk Image File on Windows 8.1 or Ubuntu

Tags: android, rom, android-firmware

I have been working on this issue for literally all day. I downloaded firmware from [here](http://www.cloudnetgo.com/CR9S.htm) and have been trying to edit it all day. The firmware comes in one file, which is formatted as a `disk image file`. I have tried to mount in Ubuntu and Windows, I have tried converting the files to different `ext`'s, I've also tried unpacking it using Android Kitchen, Linux Reader, and even Power ISO. Nothing can get this thing to open. Does anybody have ANY idea were I can go from here? Before anybody says "Oh you gotta take the `system.img`" stuff I know-- it is locked inside the main .img file. I need to get through that before I can actually start to edit it. I have no idea where to go from here so any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that if the file is already an ext4 then I can mount it directly into my Linux VM using the command `sudo mount -t ext4 -o loop system.img mountfolder/` hope this helps!

Comment: Nope. You will receive error `wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`. You must extract fs first using simg2img